# Is the following notation for the interval correct?

Tags: inequality

For the inequality

$$0<x\leq\tfrac83 \textrm{ and } x\leq2$$
I have the answer

$$(0,\tfrac83] \cup (-\infty, 2]$$

Is this accurate? I'm just trying to figure out the notation. Should I flip it around to make it $(-\infty, 2]\cup (0,\tfrac83]$ ?

Also for the 2nd question
$$x>3 \textrm{ or } −6\leq x$$
I have the answer $$(3,\infty) \cup [-6, \infty)$$

OR should I flip it around and make it $[-6, \infty) \cup (3,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you want something the satisfies *BOTH* $0 < x \le 8/3$ and $x \le 2$.

To get *BOTH* you need the intersect.  Th union means one or the other, maybe both, but maybe just one or the other.

So the answer is $(0, 8/3] \cap (-\infty, 2] = (0, 2]$.

The second one you *do* want the union because you want one or the other (and maybe both).

But you have to actually figure out what $(3, \infty] \cup [-6, \infty)$ actually is.  Hint:  $(3, \infty) \subset [-6, \infty)$.

As for "flipping".  $A \cup B = B \cup A$ and $A \cap B = B \cap A$ so flipping will never make any difference whatsoever.  (Although it may help you see how to evaluate the unions or intersections.)

Comment: Yes this makes sense now but I failed to see it, now I do.

And = intersect where both of the inequality has to exist, so x<=2 does not exist between 2 and 8/3... That is why I couldn't do (0,8/3].. Thanks for the help.

Or means the value where x can exist no matter if it doesn't exist in the other interval.

Answer (score 0):

The union of two sets is a commutative operation so for the first one, you can write it like that. You can simplify it by writing (-infinity,8/3). The same can be said for the second one but you can simplify it to [-6,infinity).

Comment: Except the union is the wrong thing to do in the first case.  The OP wanted the intersection.  (Also commutative.)

Comment: Whoops! I didn't read it properly, I just saw the union and simplified it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** Your "flipped" answers are just as correct as the "unflipped" answers.

However, none of the answers appears to be correct, if I am interpreting your questions correctly.

The word "and" usually indicates an intersection (for the first question).

And the union of two overlapping intervals is always just another interval (for the second question).

Comment: So what would be your answer for it? As far as I know what I done is correct..

Comment: For (1) I would say $(0,2]$ and for (2) I would say $[-6,\infty)$. I was intending to give hints instead of just the plain answer, but here ya go. You should try to figure out why this is right.

Comment: as - 6 < 3 the the union of [-6, inf)  and (3, inf) is [-6, inf).